# Vector components perpendicular to a given vector

Tags: geometry

I have been asked to find the components of a vector: **p** - **b** = (1,6,2) perpendicular to a vector **ẽ**. I have already calculated that the components of **p** - **b** along **ẽ** is vector (8/9, 4/9, -8/9).

How do I calculate **p** - **b**'s components perpendicular to **ẽ**?

I know the answer is (1/9, 50/9, 26/9) but I am unsure the formula to calculate this

i.e. is there a formula similar to **p** - **b**'s components along **ẽ** is equal to [(**p** - **b**) . **ẽ**]**ẽ**

Comment: vector=(component along direction e)+(component perpendicular to e).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if you add up the two components of the vector along a perpendicular to some direction, you should recover the original vector.